# Prove $\frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\varphi(t_x)}$ is a probability density function

Tags: probability, density-function, moment-generating-functions

Let $X_1$ be a random variable. I need to prove that the function $f(x_1) = \frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\varphi(t_x)}$ is a density function, whereby $\varphi(t)$ is the moment generating function of $X_1$ and $t_x$ is the value of $t$ for which $g(t) = tx - \log \varphi(t), x> 0$ is maximised. In other words, $$x = (\log \varphi)'(t_x) \implies x = \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_1e^{t_xX_1}]}{\mathbb{E}[e^{t_xX_1}]}. $$We assume that all moments of $X_1$ are finite, $\varphi(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX_1}]< \infty, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$. In the book I am reading one finds the following comment: "If the distribution of $X_1$ is transformed with the density $\frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\varphi(t_x)},$ then the new distribution will have the expectation $x."$ Can somebody understand what is the exact transformation that is meant and why $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x_1)dx_1   = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\varphi(t_x)}dx_1 = 1.$$ As far as I can see, one may mean the following: we may write $ x = \mathbb{E}[X_1\frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{t_xX_1}]}] = \mathbb{E}[Y_1],$ whereby we set for the pdf of $Y_1$ to be $f_{Y_1}(y_1) =  \frac{e^{t_xY_1}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{t_xY_1}]}.$ In that case,$$\mathbb{E}[Y_1] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} Y_1\frac{e^{t_xY_1}}{\mathbb{E}[e^{t_xY_1}]}dy_1 = x.$$ But I am not sure. In particular, I do not see how $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x_1)dx_1 = 1.$

Comment: Something wrong with the formula of $f(x)$ as it is a random function of $X_1$ (the nominator of $f(x)$ is a function of $X_1$. Indeed, the function $f$ need to be firstly a determinist function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I provided more context. Can you look at it again ?

Comment: As in the first comment, the function $f$ you defined cannot be a density function as it is not determinist.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong with the notation, just as you are saying. But I also provided some more context and quoted the book. Can't you see where the problem is ?

Comment: @NN2. Given the answers below, I am curius about the question you raised. Is it still valid?

Comment: Your questions before being edited is some kind of $f(\color{red}{x}) = \frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\varphi(t_x)}$ and it leaded to misunderstanding because this function involves a random variable $X_1$. I guess after being edited to $f(\color{blue}{x_1}) = \frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\varphi(t_x)}$, people began to understand what you had wanted (even if there is still error, the formula should be $f(\color{blue}{x_1}) = e^{t_x\color{blue}{x}_1}/ \varphi(t_x)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Transforming with density means *pointwise multiplication* with the original density

Start again with your formula $x=\mathbb E\bigl[X_1\frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\mathbb E[e^{t_xX_1}]}\bigr] = \mathbb E[Y_1]$, where $Y_1$ should be the transformed random variable. If we write the left expectation as an integral, we see
$$
\mathbb E\bigl[X_1\frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\mathbb E[e^{t_xX_1}]}\bigr] = \int_{\mathbb R} x_1\frac{e^{t_xx_1}}{\mathbb E[e^{t_xx_1}]} \mathbb P_{X_1}(\mathrm dx_1),
$$
or, if $X_1$ has a density $f_{X_1}$,
$$
\mathbb E\bigl[X_1\frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\mathbb E[e^{t_xX_1}]}\bigr] = \int_{\mathbb R} x_1\frac{e^{t_xx_1}}{\mathbb E[e^{t_xX_1}]} f_{X_1}(x_1)\mathrm dx_1 = \int_{\mathbb R} x_1 f(x_1) f_{X_1}(x_1)\mathrm dx_1.
$$
You see, the density of $Y_1$ is not $f(x_1)$, but rather the product $f(x_1)f_{X_1}(x_1)$. And this is really a pdf:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f(x_1) f_{X_1}(x_1)\mathrm dx_1 = \mathbb E\left[f(X_1)\right] = \mathbb E\bigl[\frac{e^{t_xX_1}}{\mathbb E[e^{t_xX_1}]}\bigr] = 1.
$$
If $X_1$ has no density, it works the same way, but we have to work with the measures themselves, $\mathbb P_{Y_1}(\mathrm dx_1) = f(x_1)\mathbb P_{X_1}(\mathrm dx_1)$. This is a probability measure because
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \mathbb P_{Y_1}(\mathrm dx_1) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x_1)\mathbb P_{X_1}(\mathrm dx_1) = \mathbb E[f(X_1)] = 1.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Assuming, as you do, that $X_1$ has density $f_{X_1},$ how do you conclude that the r.v. $f(X_1)$ has also density $f_{X_1}$, in other words, how do you show $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x_1)f_{X_1}(x_1)dx_1 = \mathbb{E}[f(X_1)]$?

Comment: @user996159 That is just writing the expectation as integral over the density. For any measurable function $h$, $X$ with density $f$: $\mathbb E[h(X)] = \int h(x)f(x)\mathrm dx$.

Comment: That's clear. My question was about the density of $f(X_1)$ and not of $X_1.$ In case the density of $f(X_1)$ is $f_{X_1},$ then the conclusion is straitforward.

Comment: Also, in case $X_1$ has no density, how do you use $\mathbb{P}_{Y_1}(dx_1)=f(x_1)\mathbb{P}_{X_1}(dx_1)$ to show the same thing ?

Comment: If $X_1$ has no density, how do you get this, $\mathbb{P}_{Y_1}(dx_1) = f(x_1)\mathbb{P}_{X_1}(dx_1)$ ? I am asking you since this reminds me on the Radon-Nikodym density function (from the measure $\mathbb{P_{X_1}}$ to the measure $\mathbb{P_{Y_1}}$) for which we do not make here any assumptions for it to hold such as absolute continuity. I will appreciate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is a Radon-Nikodym density. But I think you got the condition wrong. Put simply, the theorem states: measurable density<=>absolutely continuous measure. We are starting on the left side here.

Comment: But if you start at the left hand side, you already assume that the density exists. How do we know it exists ? If it exists, then the equation holds. We only assumed that X_1 has no pdf.

Comment: The book says "transformed with the density [$f(x)$]". The density is given, we compute the resulting probability distribution.

Answer (score 3):

In the definition of $f_1$ you miss another probability density $f$. Let me change a bit your confusing notations.

$$f_1(x)=\frac{e^{tx}}{\varphi(t)}f(x)dx$$ where
$\varphi(t)=\int_{R}e^{tx}f(x)dx.$ If $X$ has density $f$ and $X_1$ has density $f_1$  then the mean $m_1$ of $X_1$ is

$$m_1=\int_{R}x_1f_1(x_1)dx_1=\frac{\varphi'(t)}{\varphi(t)}=\frac{d}{dt}\log \varphi(t).$$